# Truncate High order terms

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

Suppose I want to compute this :
`Series[Sin[1/f], {f, Infinity, 10}]`
but finally I prefer `Sin[1/f]` up to the fourth order in `1/f`. How can I do this ?

My first idea was to use the `O[]` function but it didn't work because `1/f is not a valid variable`.

My second idea was to use firstly `/. f -> 1/eps` and then `O[eps]^4` but it didn't work as well...

Note also that, for many reasons, `Series[Sin[1/f], {f, Infinity, 4}]` is not a solution to me !

Comment: `Normal@Series[Sin[1/f], {f, Infinity, 4}]`  (if that doesn't do show what result you expect)

Comment: I learned a new `Series` trick today. To my surprise, this can be done as `Series[Sin[1/f], {f, Infinity, 10}] + O[f, Infinity]^4`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Actually, since `O[...]` turns things into  `SeriesData` anyway, you can even simply say `Sin[1/f]+O[f,Infinity]^4`.

Comment: @Jens Yeah, that gives the right series, though it seems that the post calls for a way to handle the truncation once a higher order series has already been computed.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yes - of course I already guessed  that's why you wrote it that way (after posting the comment)...

Answer (score 3):

As Daniel's comment shows, your idea using `O[...]` was probably on the right track (if I understood your goal correctly). The error message goes away if you do it this way (you probably typed something like `O[1/f]`):

```
Sin[1/f] + O[f, Infinity]^4
```

> $$\frac{1}{f}-\frac{1}{6
>    f^3}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{f}\right)^4\right)$$

```
Sin[1/f] + O[f, Infinity]^10
```

> $$\frac{1}{f}-\frac{1}{6
>    f^3}+\frac{1}{120
>    f^5}-\frac{1}{5040
>    f^7}+\frac{1}{362880
>    f^9}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{f}\right)^{10}\right)$$

Interestingly, *Mathematica* formats the big oh in terms of $1/f$ whereas you can't input it that way in the usual input line. However, you *can* in fact input the $O(1/f)$ variant if you copy the `O` part of the output from above, $O\left(\left(\frac{1}{f}\right)^{4}\right)$ and paste it into your input next to the function you want to expand.

Comment: Similarly one cannot input `O[x-c]` but instead must use `O[x,c]`. Actually I like this because it means one need not wonder if `O[x-c]` and `O[-c+x]` will be seen as equivalent, or what evaluation might do to the innards of that `O[...]`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Makes sense - sometimes people do get spoiled by the more idiomatic `TraditionalForm` and try to enter things in that more ambiguous way, too.